# Flash AS3 callback function on clearInterval

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am new in Flash ActionScript 3.0. I need callback function on setInterval, I did like

There is a basket called ownmouse. and it is attached with mouse.

```
ownmouse.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,fun);
function fun(Eve:Event) {
    ownmouse.startDrag(true);
    Mouse.hide();
}
```

ball fall from top of the flash document with setInterval.

```
var myInterval = setInterval(fallBall,1);
ownmouse.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,controlCursor);


function controlCursor(MouseMove:Event) {
    var xaxis:int = mouseX;
    var yaxis:int = mouseY;
    var ballXaxis = ball.x;
    var ballYaxis = ball.y;

    if((ballXaxis+10)>=xaxis && (ballXaxis-10)<=xaxis && (ballYaxis)>=yaxis && (ballYaxis-10)<=yaxis) {
    clearInterval(myInterval, function() {
        myBall.gotoAndPlay(10)
    });
    }

    if(yaxis>620) {
        ownmouse.stopDrag();
        ownmouse.y = 620;
        Mouse.show();
    } else if(yaxis<420) {
        ownmouse.stopDrag();
        ownmouse.y = 430;
        Mouse.show();
    }
}
```

Everything work well except following code:

```
clearInterval(myInterval, function() {
        myBall.gotoAndPlay(10)
    });
```

Is callback function possible in AS3 ? If not, how to solve such problem ?

I will appreciate your help very much :)

Answer (score 0):

clearInterval destroys intervals.
setInterval creates it and returns a number which you can put into clearInterval to destroy it.

also setTimeout performs it only once.

you also need to specify a time, in milliseconds, after the function.

I will always recommend you use Timer class because you can control it and read it easily.

Comment: Actually, i need callback function after destroys the interval.

Comment: so set a setTimeout after the interval is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

there is no callback for clearInterval. you could trigger a method yourself if your requirements for destroying it are met.
Depending on your needs, maybe a timer would be a better choice.

```
var myTimer:Timer = new timer(1000,8);// set amout 
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimeEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerDone);

function timerListener (e:TimerEvent):void{
 trace("Timer is Triggered");
}
 function timerDone(e:TimerEvent):void{
 trace("Timer finishing!");
}
myTimer.start();
```

**EDIT:**
Like i said b4, you can trigger your own method when the requirements are met. In your case with the updated source:

```
if((ballXaxis+10)>=xaxis && (ballXaxis-10)<=xaxis && (ballYaxis)>=yaxis && (ballYaxis-10)<=yaxis) {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    intervalDestroyed();
    }

function intervalDestroyed():void
{
  trace("Intervall has been cleared");
  myBall.gotoAndPlay(10);
}
```

If this is the only thing you are trying to do, you can just call whatever you need in the if:

```
if((ballXaxis+10)>=xaxis && (ballXaxis-10)<=xaxis && (ballYaxis)>=yaxis && (ballYaxis-10)<=yaxis) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
        myBall.gotoAndPlay(10);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. i did before question posting :   clearInterval(myInterval);    myBall.gotoAndPlay(10);. clearInterval worked well, but myBall.gotoAndPlay(10) worked only after moving mouse even after clearInterval. so now you understand my problem. I will appreciate your complete solution very much.

Comment: You should be using a MOUSE_MOVE event instead of an enterframe in the first place. have u tried with my intervalDestroyed method?